# How can I get a "start of transaction" timestamp in Spring + JPA + Hibernate setup?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, transactions

I am using Spring 3.0.5, JPA, Hibernate 3.5.5-Final and Spring's JpaTransactionManager. Anyone know an easy way to programmatically get a timestamp for the start of each transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Idea

Since [JpaTransactionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.html) extends [AbstractPlatformTransactionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.html)
and every transaction starts with a call of the [#getTransaction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.html#getTransaction%28org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition%29) method, you can write an [aspect](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html) around that method.

### Aspect

```
@Aspect
public class AspectAroundTransactions() {
   @Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.*.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(..))" )
   public void newTransaction() {}

   @Before("newTransaction() && args(transactionDefinition,..)")
   public void beforeStartOfTransaction(TransactionDefinition transactionDefinition) {
      // here goes you code
      long start = System.nanoTime();
      System.out.println("Transaction " + transactionDefinition.getName() + " started at " + start );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And I think I can use TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource to associate the timestamp with the tx.

Comment: Are you sure? With TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(Object, Object) you bind a resource to a Thread, not to a Transaction, so if you are using multiple transactions in the same Thread, you would always overwrite your timestamp...

Comment: I had some hassles with the aspect stuff so I just extended JpaTransactionManager (not as clean I know) and used doBegin and doCleanupAfterCompletion to set/clear the timestamp. I don't have multiple tx active on one thread so thats ok for now.

Comment: since all tx managers should implement PlatformTransactionManager interface (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager.html), maybe it's better to make an aspect that goes around it's getTransaction method (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager.html#getTransaction%28org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition%29).

Comment: So the pointcout should look like this: @Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(..))" )

Comment: AOPing PlatformTransactionManager will result in NPE because logger become null. That's what I found.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to use a filter in WEB-INF to do this - it would inject a timestamp into the request context as a named attribute. The timestamp would not be a "transaction" timestamp, but a request timestamp. But it will do what you want, I suspect.